# NameError: name 'scipy' is not defined in Tensorflow 2.0

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, deep-learning

I am trying to train a model using CNN to identify cats and dogs by *Tensorflow 2.15.0 GPU*. However, when running the program, there is an error saying `NameError: name 'scipy' is not defined`

### Data generator

The dataset can be found by https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/tongpython/cat-and-dog/data

```
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)
test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)
# loading training data
train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    train_dir, 
    target_size=(64, 64), 
    batch_size=20, 
    class_mode='binary'
)
# loading validation data
test_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    test_dir, 
    target_size=(64, 64), 
    batch_size=20, 
    class_mode='binary'
)
```

### Model

The model is built and compiled like below with three convenlutional layers and two netural layers:

```
# Build
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(64, 64, 3)), 
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2, 2), 
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'), 
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2, 2), 
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu'), 
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2, 2), 
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(), 
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(512, activation='relu'), 
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')
])
# Compile
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', 
              optimizer=Adam(learning_rate=1e-4), 
              metrics=['acc'])
```

### Training

But when the program runs this line, the error appears.

```
history = model.fit_generator(
    train_generator, 
    steps_per_epoch=400, 
    epochs=20, 
    validation_data=test_generator, 
    validation_steps=100, 
    verbose=2
)
```

The error is shown below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/liu/tensor/demo2/test1.py", line 65, in <module>
    history = model.fit_generator(
  File "/home/liu/tensor/tensor_venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/engine/training.py", line 2913, in fit_generator
    return self.fit(
  File "/home/liu/tensor/tensor_venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 70, in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
  File "/home/liu/tensor/tensor_venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/preprocessing/image.py", line 2526, in apply_affine_transform
    if scipy is None:
NameError: name 'scipy' is not defined
```

#### What I think

- I'm wondering if there is a need to install `'scipy'` manually. But it seems that this shouldn't happen.
- Problem in function `fit_generator()` like incompatibility with Python 3.10
- Incorrect image format

Comment: Both `ImageDataGenerator` ([link](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/image/ImageDataGenerator#used-in-the-notebooks)) and `model.fit_generator` are deprecated. I can't even find `fit_generator` in the current docs, but when I call it with TF 2.13, I get a UserWarning about its deprecation. Instead of `fit_generator`, you can just use `.fit`, it can handle generators as well. For substitution of the `ImageDataGenerator`, you can follow the link and look at the grey box.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to run either `pip install scipy` or `conda install scipy` to fix the error.